# Fill Series with 1m frequency skipping weekends

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, stockquotes

I have currency quotes in pandas dataframe, column 0 - date/time, column 1 - close price.
And as its a 1 minute period, there are a lot of gaps.
So I need to apply `.asfreq(freq='T')` on close series, but also I must skip all weekends.
How do I do that? Unfourtunately, `.asfreq(freq='BT')` doesnt work

Comment: `df = df.asfreq(freq='T'); df = df[df[0].dt.dayofweek.lt(5)]`?

Comment: What ``.lt(5)`` means?

Comment: And also df[0] throws ``KeyError: 0``

Comment: Replace 0 with your first column name, lt means less than.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = data.asfreq('15T')
data = data[data.index.dayofweek<5]
```

It works this way.